# Web scraping html page with no tags as delimiter

Tags: html, excel, vba, dom

I'm trying to import into a string array all lines of text in a web page. The URL is here: [Vaticano-La Sacra Bibbia-Genesi-Cap.1](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ITA0001/__P1.HTM).

Unfortunately (maybe a choice of the web designer), in the tag there aren't ID's or CLASS. All the rows are separated by 1 or more < BR > element. Start and end text is separated from a simple menu by 2 tag < HR >.
A clean extract of page code is here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emanuele_tinari/ebho95yx/).
I find a way to bring the text. And now what I do in VBA till now:

**Note:** objDoc is a Public variable coming from another module, fill with a .responseText without problems.

```
Public Sub ScriviXHTML(strBook As String, intNumCap As Integer)
Dim strDati2 As String
Dim TagBr As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim BrElement As IHTMLElement
Dim intElement As Integer
Dim objChild as Object
Dim strData, strTextCont, strNodeVal, strWholeText As String

Set objDoc2 = New HTMLDocument
Set objDoc2 = objDoc
Set objDoc = Nothing

'Put in variable string HTML code of the web page.
strDati2 = objDoc2.body.innerHTML
'Set in the variable object TAG type BR.
Set TagBr = objDoc2.body.getElementsByTagName("BR")

'Loop for all BRs in the page.
For Each BrElement In TagBr
    'Here I try to get the NextSibling element of the <br>
    ' because seems contain the text I'm looking for.
    Set objChild = BrElement.NextSibling
    With objChild
        ' Here I try to put in the variables 
        strData = Trim("" & .Data & "")
        strTextCont = Trim("" & .textContent & "")
        strNodeVal = Trim("" & .NodeValue & "")
        strWholeText = Trim("" & .wholeText & "")
    End With
    intElement = intElement + 1

Next BrElement
```

Two questions:
1) Is it, about you, the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?
2) Sometimes the Element.NextSibling.Data doesn't exist, with an Error of runtime '438', so I manually move the point of sospension of the routine to by-pass the error. How can I intercept this error? [Please not with a simple On Error Resume Next!]... better: how can I use an If...Then... End If statement to check if in NextSibling exist the Data member?
 
Thanks at all.

Comment: No, because strchild is an [Object] :-)

Comment: I correct some variables names so it's more clear what they containing.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get all the text as follows:

```
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, xhr As Object, html As New HTMLDocument
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "http://www.vatican.va/archive/ITA0001/__P1.HTM", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
        html.body.innerHTML = sResponse
        [A1] = Replace$(Replace$(regexRemove(html.body.innerHTML, "<([^>]+)>"), " &nbsp;", Chr$(32)), Chr$(10), Chr$(32))
    End With
End Sub

Public Function regexRemove(ByVal s As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = pattern
    End With

    If regex.test(s) Then
        regexRemove = regex.Replace(s, vbNullString)
    Else
        regexRemove = s
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Did you try this solution I wrote for you?